# Не удаётся отправить письмо phpmailer

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

Пытаюсь отправить обычное письмо из примера phpmailer, но выдаёт ошибку `Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: Could not instantiate mail function.`

Вот код, в котором появилась ошибка:

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

//require 'vendor/autoload.php';
require 'PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';
require 'PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
try{

        //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('ivan.aleksandrov1007@gmail.com', 'Mailer');
    $mail->addAddress('aleksandrov262003@gmail.com');

    //Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  //Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
    $mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';
    
    $mail->send();
    echo 'Message has been sent';
} catch (Exception $e) {
echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}
```

Если кто-то сталкивался с подобным и знает решение, просьба написать его сюда. Буду признателен..)

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297084/phpmailer-error-could-not-instantiate-mail-function

Comment: ]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297084/phpmailer-error-could-not-instantiate-mail-function]